# PHP. Работа с массивами

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть вопрос. У меня есть 2 массива.
Мне нужно написать код так, чтобы 1вая данная масива 1 пробежалась по всем данным массива 2 , и если она существует в массиве 2 - удалилась.
Ломаю голову над этим и как правильно это написать.
За любую помощь был бы благодарен.

Comment: В зависимости от того, что нужно, используйте [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php) или [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: Плохая привычка, говорить у меня есть и не показывать.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно же только 1-й элемент удалить:

```
foreach($array2 as &$item) {
    if ($item ==$array1[0]) unset($item);
}
sort($array2);
```

Comment: unset($item) не сработает =) это скопированное значение элемента массива. Нужно тогда так foreach($array2 as $key => $item) {
    if ($item ==$array1[0]) unset($array2[$key]);
}

Comment: Я исправил. Забыл амперсанд добавить перед ссылкой

Comment: Теперь unset разрушит ссылку, но не элемент массива

Comment: Неправда! При амперсанде удаляется элемент! Сначала изучите тему, прежде чем критиковать

Answer (score -2):

```
$array1 = array(["apple"], ["pen"]);
$array2 = array(["applepen"], ["pen"]);    

foreach($array1 as $r1){

      foreach($array2 as $key => $r2){
        if($r1 == $r2){
          unset($array2[$key]);
        }
      }

    }

    echo "<br>";
    print_r($array1);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($array2);
```

На выходе получим:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => apple ) [1] => Array ( [0] => pen ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => applepen ) )
```